# prove that $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

I was looking on a problem in which we need to find rational numbers between 2 numbers. In the solution it was told that to find rational numbers between a and b we need to find $\frac{a+b}{2}$ i.e., $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$. But I wanted to know if there any prove that satisfies $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$. If yes, then what is the proof?

Comment: Are we assuming that $a<b$?

Comment: If $a < b$, then $a+a < a +b < b +b$ i.e. $2a < (a+b) < 2b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a<b$, then $\frac a2<\frac b2$.

Now, take the inequality $\frac a2<\frac b2$ and try to add some number to both sides. Try to add such a number that one side becomes $a$.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $a \leq b$. Then $(a+a)\; \leq \;(a + b)\; \leq (b+b)$. Dividing by two, we find the desired result: $$a \leq \frac{a+b}{2} \leq b.$$